# Blocks added when mining monero

Tags: monerod, mining

My computer is mining monero with monerod daemon pointing to my monero wallet, and I found in the logs some messages like this one:

[timestamp]    BLOCK ADDED AS ALTERNATIVE ON HEIGHT 1382864

I thought my miner had found a block but there is nothing new in my monero wallet. Please explain the meaning of this log message and how does it looks like when the miner find a block and add some monero in my account. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

That means the blockchain had a re-org because 2 blocks were found at almost the same time by 2 different miners. The one with bigger difficulty came later and pushed the other one out.

Comment: Thanks, so  how does it looks like when the miner find a block and add some monero in your account balance ?

Comment: If you find a block, it says "Found block for difficulty XXXXXX".